# QGIS Layout problem - when rendering SVG a black rectangle appears

Tags: qgis, layouts, svg

I have created a `Layout`, in this Layout there is a map. In this map there are `SVG Markers`.

When I'm in the map composer, the `SVG Markers` are shown perfectly.

[image]

But when I generate a Layout, a black box appears.

[image]

Comment: the SVG markers look the same in both screenshot... are you sure the black box are not from the basemap?

Comment: I agree with @JGH this look more like missing basemap tile than SVG rendering problem. You could try to zoom on your base map to get the same zoom level as your export (on export QGIS fetch higher zoom level tile to match the export resolution) and pan to the black area to see if the tile load and try exporting again (the tile should be cached, you may also try to increase the cache size)

Comment: When I disable SVG Markers the rectangles disappears. So the problem are the SVG Markers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I find a solution, and is edit with NotePad++ the SVG file and delete `<flowRoot></flowRoot>`.

My text was:

```
>     <flowRoot
>        style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
>        id="flowRoot4530"
>        xml:space="preserve"><flowRegion
>          id="flowRegion4532"><rect
>            y="170.07877"
>            x="170.07874"
>            height="238.11023"
>            width="498.89764"
>            id="rect4534" /></flowRegion><flowPara
>          id="flowPara4536" /></flowRoot>
```